# Parametrized surface is vaguely tetrahedral?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, parametrization

My son has been looking at space curves parametrized as
$$ x\mapsto (\cos(ax), \sin(bx), \sin(cx)) $$
for various integer triples. When $(a,b,c)$ involve few, but distinct, primes, the image seems to lie on a surface that is something like an inflated tetrahedron. There is a lot to chew on there but my question is more well-defined.

A slight variant brings what looks like a parametrization of this surface:
$$ (x,t) \mapsto (\cos(t+5x), \sin(t+7x), \sin(2x)) $$
Is it easy to determine the equation defining this surface?

Comment: These are basically 3D Lissajous curves. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_orbit

Comment: [Interactive 3D Lissajous plotter](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNULFuwyAQ3f0VJ3cIjlAUxWqHSkgdqk4ZMnSrKuuCcUzq-BCc3d8vhrT1crzj3rv34AHqVzjaEPBKUyhm9GLDm6p4sSMbj5qL1nTQCFS1hLM6SNDqUYKjOA-qftrLAqDzeDPq3U9GQov-S73hECJ2xgdnNNv5d4oTUzO5FtlkUvUc9XEDKJgjk7z40BQEbrmSEOwozn9IR_RZJfop0h0uruytbtxAXLeikyD2Eg5bZ6NkuWzuOfORtdybm4n6cklagu1SZDAxDJSDvfRcJp7zdF2y07iQV09JmlV_l5Lnni4eXW913nDahZ6-Rf6dVGV2V6nKlYX6h9UPCQmCxw==&lang=sage), using Sage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this affine surface is given by $ u^2 + v^2 +w^2 - 2uvw =1 $. Of course, if we restrict to real points with the given parametrization, we impose $ -1 \le u,v,w \le 1 $ where it is indeed a bulging tetrahedron with vertices $$ (1,1,1), (-1,-1,1), (1,-1,-1),(-1,1,-1) $$

To get the equation, note that $$  \sin(t+7x) = \sin(t+5x+2x) = \sin(t+5x) \cos(2x) + \cos(t+5x) \sin(2x) $$

So $$ (v-uw)^2 = (1-u^2)(1-w^2) \implies u^2 + v^2 +w^2 - 2uvw =1  $$ giving the desired equation. I just haven't checked that any point on this surface with the given bounds has the above parametrization but this shouldn't be hard now.